# Cannot get element inside distant parent div using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

In a dom which has many of the blocks like the one below, I'd like to get name of `pid` element (i.d `123`) when `link` is clicked:

```
<div class="a-post">
    <a class="pid" name="123"></a>
    <div class="row">
        <p>Some text</p>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <p>Othe text </p>
        </div>

        <br>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-1">
                <img class="link" src="link.svg">
            </div>

        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".link").click(function () {
    let pid = $(this).parent(".a-post").find(".pid").attr('name');
    console.log('pid is:', pid);
 }
});
```

But I get `pid is: undefined`

How can I fix this?

Comment: Just a note: the name attribute for anchors is obsolete and shouldn't be used

Comment: @Pete so what do you advise to use instead?

Comment: use an id or a data attribute? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use `.closest()` and not `.parent()`, because `.parent()` only goes 1 step up. `.closest()` will continue until it reach the top or finds the element.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".link").click(function() {
    let pid = $(this).closest(".a-post").find(".pid").attr('name');
    console.log('pid is:', pid);
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="a-post">
  <a class="pid" name="123"></a>
  <div class="row">
    <p>Some text</p>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <p>Othe text </p>
    </div>

    <br>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-1">
        <img class="link" src="link.svg">
      </div>

    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```